# How to use karate.callSingle() in karate-config.js?

Tags: karate

I am using an authorization token in all my feature files . To generate the authorization token i need to call a particular feature file(token.feature) . Since I am using the token in all features I keep calling the same feature file again and again. The solution i found is the use of karate.callSingle() in karate-config.js but i dont know how to use karate.callSingle().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `karate-config.js` you can do this:

```
var config = { myprop: 'myvalue', myurl: 'somevalue' };
var result = karate.callSingle('classpath:token.feature', config);
config.token = result.token; // assuming you did 'def token'
return config;
```

Now all your features can use the variable `token`.

This is explained in the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#hooks

Comment: My karate config file is as follows
function init() 
{
return {

        env: karate.env,
        API_URL: karate.properties['baseURL'],
        Origin_Url: karate.properties['OriginURL'],
        ID: karate.properties['clientId'],
        SECRET: karate.properties['clientSecret'],
        
        };
}
Should i include the var result within return? @peter

Comment: @dhaneshbabu I'm confused. please open another question if needed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51399404/how-to-use-karate-callsingle-in-my-karate-config-js @peter . I have attached a snap of my karate.config file