# How to use karate.callSingle() in my karate-config.js?

Tags: karate

The following is my karate-config.js file. The classpath for the feature that i want to call only once is classpath:com/test/scenario/accessToken.feature . where should i include the karate.callSingle()

```
function init() {
    karate.log('Env set to ', karate.env);
    karate.log('baseURL ', karate.properties['baseURL']);
    karate.log('OriginURl',karate.properties['OriginURL'])


    return {
        env: karate.env,

        SECRET: karate.properties['clientSecret'],
        TOKEN: {
            "CSRF": "",
            'ACCESS': ""
        },



        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include it anywhere, before you return the JSON. I suggest you take the help of someone who knows basic JavaScript near you, please. It is clearly mentioned in the documentation that this is for advanced users. If you have not understood my answer to your previous question, I have nothing more to add: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51288570/143475

But let me try again. On line 13 you can do:

```
var result = karate.callSingle('classpath:com/freshworks/freshid/test/scenario/accessToken.feature');
```

And then on line 20 (this totally depends on how you have written accessToken.feature, I can't believe I am still trying to help you)

```
TOKEN: {
  CSRF: result.csrf,
  ACCESS: result.access
}
```

Comment: Sorry to wake up such an old thread. I was looking through the docs and for reference I needed to know the behaviour of ‘callSingle’ for parallel execution. I need to do tear down only once before parallel execution. Thanks Peter we are having great results with your framework

Comment: @mactwixs yes, `karate.callSingle()` is precisely for that use-case. please read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#hooks